# I Would like help in changing the Title on my toolbar to the screen i'm currently at

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

This is the code in my MainActivity.java:

[image]

This is the code in my activity_main.xml:

[image]

Comment: So when you got a warning that you cannot post two pictures, you posted them as links, instead of [just posting code as code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/11683). Please don't do that.

Comment: The way you are asking question is wrong read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for batter response

Comment: Please supply your code in the question, not in linked images (!). Also, describe what you want to achieve, what you tried and what happened. Your question doesn't contain anything, not even a full sentence! Put some effort into this!

Answer (score 1):

Call this method where you want to set title on toolbar. you can define as public in activity so entire your fragment can change title with this method.

```
 public void setTitle(String title) {
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use the following code..............

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"  
 android:id="@+id/toolbar"  
 android:layout_width="match_parent"  
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
 android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"  
 android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"  
 app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >  

<TextView  
   android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"  
   android:layout_width="match_content"  
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
   android:gravity="center"  
   android:singleLine="true"  
   android:text="Title"  
   android:textColor="@android:color/white"  
   android:textSize="18sp"  
   android:textStyle="bold" />  

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```